# A nodal theorem in 1D

Tags: differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory

Consider a 1D zero-energy Schrödinger equation on the half-line,

$(-\partial_x^2 + V(x))\psi(x)=0, \quad x \in (0, \infty)$

with a zero boundary condition $\psi(0) = 0$.

Is it true that if the zero-energy solution $\psi(x)$ has $N$ nodes in $(0, \infty)$, then $V(x)$ has exactly $N$ negative energy bound states?

If yes, may I ask for the reference?

Comment: Yes, this works and is very classical. Search for something like "oscillation theory." (The claim in your second paragraph about 0 being an eigenvalue is incorrect, or perhaps you meant to say that the essential spectrum is $[0,\infty)$, which is correct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. This is essentially the Sturm oscillation theorem.

A pedagogical reference is

B. Simon, in *Sturm-Liouville Theory* (Birkhäuser Basel, 2005), pp. 29—43.

Many thanks to Christian Remling for the right keyword.